# Javascript uncaught error undefined is not a function in listener

Tags: javascript, function, appendchild, addchild

```
 var HelloWorldLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
sprite:null,
ctor:function(){
    var myWorld;
    this._super();
            var winsize = cc.director.getWinSize();
    myWorld = new cc.Sprite(res.HelloWorld_png);
    myWorld.attr({
        x: winsize.width / 2,
        y: winsize.height / 2,
        scale: 1,
        rotation: 180
    });
    this.addChild(myWorld, 0);
    var centerpos = cc.p(winsize.width / 2, winsize.height / 2);
    cc.eventManager.addListener(cc.EventListener.create({
        event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ALL_AT_ONCE,
        onTouchesBegan: function(touches, event) {
            console.log("onTouchesBegan!");
            var spritebg;
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                spritebg = cc.Sprite.create(res.Hat_png);
                spritebg.setPosition(
                     (Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) + 100),
                     (Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) + 100));              
                //this.addChild(spritebg);
                myWorld.appendChild(spritebg);
            }   
        }
    }), this);

 }  
 });
```

No matter what I do, I keep getting the same error when I try to add the child when I click on the screen.  I'm new to javascript and don't really get the language.  I got the same error message when I tried adding the children inside of a function.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: myWorld.appendChild(spritebg);

Answer (score 0):

Having had a look at the [Cocos2D reference for `cc.Sprite`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V2.2/symbols/cc.Sprite.html), it seems that there isn't a method `appendChild` on the `Sprite` object.  The error you are getting is because you are trying to call a method that does not exist.

Perhaps you wanted `myWorld.addChild(spritebg);` instead?

Comment: tried and failed.  Also tried this.addChild(spritebg)